# The YUI maze: How do I get my CSS minified?

Tags: css, minify, yui

What steps should I follow to be able to minify CSS from the command line (Windows or Solaris)?

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/#using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean - compile CSS?

CSS is getting interpreted by browser, there is no compilation involved.

**Edit**

Ok, after the clarification: you could use http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ yui compressor tool. It is a java program, so should run both on Solaris and Windows. It could also minimize your javascript.